# jQuery blockUI how to remove message frame

Tags: jquery, blockui

Hi I have a jQuery blockUI blocking a div but I want to remove the message frame.

[image]

```
$('#profile1').block({
                message: '<div class="pleaseWait"><div class="circle"></div></div>'
            });
```

> Any clue?

Comment: Are you talking about the message block that comes up (the white box with a green circle) or the actual message behind the box? If the first, you can probably just set the message to `message: ''` or an empty div with no class: `message: '<div></div>'`

Comment: Yes the gray border with white background. I can't do message: '' because I have other thing displayed there.